# Creating a custom form with ability to query and submit to SQL

Tags: database, forms

I need to create a rather unique customer invoice/purchase form and I have been searching google with different questions for a week without finding an answer, hopefully someone here can point me in the right direction.

We are currently using Microsoft Access for the form and database. It basically has 2 parts, the customer info and the invoice. I want to create this on our new wordpress site so that it can be accessed from anywhere, not just the single computer at the office. I would be happy with it being either a form accessible from the admin panel or even just as a page on the site that can only be accessed by site admins.

I need to be able to have some fields query and submit, such as the customer ID field, License number field, and name field be able to query the database to autofill the customer info section for return customers. If the customer is a new customer then just have it submit the info to the customer table and assign them a customer number via sequential autonumbering. Then once the customer info is filled in be able to create an invoice for that customer, however the invoice is actually more of a purchase order because we are buying from the customer, not selling to them.

Any advice on where to get started would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: The answer to this question can fill books. I would suggest you research how SQL commands can be used in PHP to access, read and manipulate data in `.msb` files and then come back with a more specific question when **and if** you run into problems.

Comment: Yes, I realize it was a very open ended question, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for making the form in wordpress? I also noticed that the theme I am using is actually done in Gantry 5 inside of wordpress, so I am trying to figure out if I need to make the form in wordpress or in Gantry.

Comment: Have you considered using a WordPress form plugin? You'd have to find a way to import the existing data, but once you're over that hump, it would simplify things considerably. Plugins like Gravity Forms can handle large amounts and formats of data, and importers are often available.

Comment: I already did a SQL dump file of the current Access database, so importing shouldn't be that hard. The only worry I have is originally I was going to just change it from access to a SQL database and build a form with Infopath and then I found out that infopath was very limited in the abilities of the forms you create with it. Like it didn't have any way to autonumber an ID field and such. So I was worried that using a form plugin I might run in to the same problems.

Comment: After Chris Rogers suggestion I have been reading up and I think I can make my own using PDO, The other thing I am confused about is that the template is a Gantry template built in Wordpress, so I do not know if I need to make it an addition to wordpress or an addition to Gantry. Does anyone have any experience adding things to templates built on Gantry 5?

Comment: Would this be something that would help me learn to do what I asked? "Udemy Mastering PHP PDO: PHP Data Objects with CRUD Application"